# Importance of having EDU backlinks

Tags: domains, pagerank, backlinks

I've built a few links on 50 EDU / GOV websites. 1 of them has PR 8, 3 of them have PR 7, 8 of them PR6,7 of them PR5,12 of them PR4,8 of them PR3, 1 of them PR2, 6 of them PR1, 10 of them PR0. My website has PR3 and is on first page of Google/Yahoo/Bing for a few keywords that I like

How long will it take to notice a difference in PR or domain authority? (Don't tell me that PR has no value now, I know it but it is a 'fashion' thing).

So you say that DOMAIN Authority isn't an important factor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No-one can tell you exactly when the PR will be updated, since that is fully under google's control. Anyway, as Matt Cutts asserts, .edu and .gov backlinks **have no more weight** than any other extension.

I also find this quote on the web:

> Are .gov and .edu back links still considered more "link juice" than
>   the common back link?
>
> This is a common misconception--you don't get any PageRank boost from
>   having an .edu link or .gov link automatically. Hah John, I beat you
>   to it! If you get an .edu link and no one is linking to that .edu
>   page, you're not going to get any PageRank at all because that .edu
>   page doesn't have any PageRank. Matt Cutts

Comment: I wish everyone would read that so we can put an end to the arbitrary bonuses for .edu and .gov links

Comment: Link juice obtained through bought links is a nasty substance that ends up needing to be wiped off the floor.

Answer (score 4):

1. Sites do not have PageRank. Pages have PageRank. PageRank is per page, not per website. So what you are seeing is the PageRank of those sites' home pages.
2. PageRank is not nearly as important as it used to be. Nowadays it has much less value. In fact, few people, if any, consider an important ranking factor in Google's algorithm.
3. Who says having links from those websites will increase your domain authority? You don't have links on those sites' home pages and those other pages probably are worthless if they are so easy to get. I also suspect those pages are off-topic for your website which make them worth even less. I would say you should expect those links to do nothing for you at all.
4. If you're asking about PR then it isn't "a fashion thing" to you. At least not if your goal is to actually be successful. After all, someone who wants to be successful doesn't go chasing things that have no value, right? :)

Comment: I call my self Web Designer so when I sell a website my customers ask me when will we have X PR? I know very well that PageRank is only 1 of more then 200 factors that ..bla..bla..bla... anyway, while 'fighting' against customers that don't want to understand that this is NOT important or not the only factor that they have to consider, I need to check it ! :P PageRank (Page = page/article is self-explaining) is related only to a page and I know it very well too. I say it is fashion because it helps to sell stuff to 'dumb' customers. Isn't it also for you? (sorry 4 bad english!)

Comment: @maisdesign if your clients are asking about X PageRank you should be setting them straight that they should not be worrying about a number between 1-10.